# Spring Security LDAP - Problems Authenticating a User - Container Issue?

Tags: spring, ldap, containers

Let me preface this by saying I'm not well versed in Spring. I was thrown into a project at work and am trying to spin up as quickly as possible

With that in mind, I'm trying to implement spring security using Jasig's CAS and LDAP.

When I had loaded this set up from a local LDAP, things worked fine. However, since I've relocated it to the corporate LDAP, the webapp is no longer working.

At the moment, I can confirm this script successfully logs into LDAP and verifies the paths to the containers, however I get a server error before the page loads.

Code:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd" >


<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <!-- The URL of the ldap server, along with the base path that all other ldap path will be relative to -->
    <constructor-arg value="ldaps://141.161.99.74:636/dc=testing,dc=com"/>
    <property name="userDn" value="uid=OdinAdmin,ou=Specials,dc=testing,dc=com" />
    <property name="password" value="testpw" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
            <property name="userSearch" ref="ldapUserSearch"/>
    </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg ref="authoritiesPopulator" />                       <!-- Populates authorities in the UserDetails object -->
    <property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="userDetailsMapper" /> <!-- Adds OWF groups to the UserDetails object -->
</bean>

<bean id="authoritiesPopulator" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
    <constructor-arg value="ou=OdinRoles,ou=Odin,ou=Apps"/> <!-- search base for determining what roles a user has -->
    <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="cn"/>
    <!-- the following properties are shown with their default values -->
    <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_"/>
    <property name="convertToUpperCase" value="true"/>
    <property name="searchSubtree" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ldapUserSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <constructor-arg value="ou=people" /> <!-- search base for finding User records -->
    <constructor-arg value="(uid={0})" /> <!-- filter applied to entities under the search base in order to find a given user.
                                            this default searches for an entity with a matching uid -->
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
</bean>

<!-- Custom class that goes back to the ldap database to search for OWF group records and also adds
     extra attributes from the user's ldap record to the UserDetails object.
     The class implementation of this will likely need to be changed out for differnt setups -->
<bean id="userDetailsMapper" class="ozone.securitysample.authentication.ldap.OWFUserDetailsContextMapper">
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
    <constructor-arg value="ou=OdinGroups,ou=Odin,ou=Apps" /> <!-- search base for finding OWF group membership -->
    <constructor-arg value="(uniqueMember={0})" /> <!-- filter that matches only groups that have the given username listed
                                                  as a "member" attribute -->
    <property name="searchSubtree" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ldapUserService" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="ldapUserSearch" />
    <constructor-arg ref="authoritiesPopulator" />
    <property name="userDetailsMapper" ref="userDetailsMapper" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

My question is, am I allowed to have the subcontainers in the constructor-arg values for group and role searches? In my previous version, everything was in the same container. That way I could just have all that included in my base-dn and just reference the specific OU within that. Ie.  instead of

I'm not sure if that is causing the issue, but any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "subcontainers"? -- My This helps: The Constructor Args and Properties are 1:1 mapped to the classes. So in the spring configuration you can do the same, but not more or less, than with a normal `new` command in java.

Comment: @Ralph Thanks for the reply. In my original configuration, all my Roles, Groups, and Users were essentially under the same DN..

`ou=People,dc=argusldapprod,dc=argus,dc=test,dc=edu ou=OdinRoles,dc=argusldapprod,dc=argus,dc=test,dc=edu ou=OdinGroups,dc=argusldapprod,dc=argus,dc=test,dc=edu`

Now, however, the groups and roles are in different subcontainers: 

`ou=People,dc=test,dc=edu ou=OdinGroups,ou=Odin,ou=Apps,dc=test,dc=edu ou=OdinRoles,ou=Odin,ou=Apps,dc=test,dc=edu`

I didn't know if the Apps and Odin subcontainers were causing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue actually was based on the application I was implementing. It required specific role names (ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER) to function. I had to map the existing roles to these 2 through a custom Java class.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide what exactly is the error you're getting and which part actually fails? There is quite a bit of configuration in there and it'd very much help us if we narrow it down to one error or so.

P.S: I wanted this to be a comment but I'm sorry, i'm not yet allowed to comment due to the restrictions of SO.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is weird is that no stack trace is showing up in any of the logs upon logging in. My authentication to Jasig CAS and another homegrown webapp work fine with the new LDAP, but the widget framework I'm implementing is giving the problems. Any other stacktrace from it has appeared, so it's very peculiar.